# In React.js, I'm trying to add text and some other items, on top of an overlay which is on top of an image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

In a Reactjs project, I have successfully added an overlay on top of an image in order to create some opaqueness.

However, I am having trouble now adding text on top of both these items. I want the text to be on top of the overlay,centered and in white, and most importantly not effected by the overlay's opaque feature.

Here is what I have so far:

In css file:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    background: #2F5596;
    z-index: auto;
  }

.container::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
  content: '';
}

.image {
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    object-fit: cover;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 0;
}

.text {
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    object-fit: cover;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

In React.js file:

```
import logo from '../../assets/images/WhiteLettering_BlueBackground/WhiteLettering_BlueBackground_256.png';
import classes from './Layout.css';

const layout = (props) => {
    return (

        <div className={classes.container}>
            <img src={logo} className={classes.image}/>

            <div style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "white"}} >
                <h1>Dynasty Football</h1>
                <h1>A Complete Draft Tool Kit</h1>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowDown} />
            </div>

        </div>

    )
}

export default layout;
```

The text and arrow appear but they are effected by the opaqueness of the overlay.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you set the `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);` in

```
.container::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
  content: '';
}
```

?
If you'd just use a rgba value in your `container` class and get rid of the background attribute in `:before`, it would not influence your text color, like:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(47, 85, 150, .8);
  z-index: auto;
}
```

In case it should be like it is:
Another way without changing your background properties would be to add `position: relative;` to your css attributes for your text wrapper:

```
<div
  style={{
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "white",
    position: "relative".
  }}
>
  <h1>Dynasty Football</h1>
  <h1>A Complete Draft Tool Kit</h1>
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowDown} />
</div>
```

*How to position the text with vertical & horizontal align on top of the container*
As said, it is a bit hard to unterstand why your (css) is that complex to achieve what you want (e.g. why you need the `container::before` definition). But in order to achieve what you want, you could the image as a background image of a newly created background `.container_image` and setting content properties with flex box for achieving the right content align in `.container`. This is how it can look like:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: #2f5596;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container_image {
  background-image: url("logo-url");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "";
}

.content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
```

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="container_image">
    <div className="content">
      <h1>Dynasty Football</h1>
      <h1>A Complete Draft Tool Kit</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it and the text is now on top of the overlay and in white. Thanks.

However, all the text appears below the image that is underneath the opaque overlay. It is not centered vertically.

How do I have the text take over the entire space and have the image directly behind it?

Comment: @RafaelC Added some lines. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot grenzbotin.

One more item, is there anyway to have the background image not repeat across the screen. The image itself is small enough so that two can fit horizontally acroos the screen. Is there anyway restrict this so that it only shows up once, and centered both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just add the background properties `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and `background-position: center;` to the .container_image class (see my edited post)